# User-based settings for Custom Timer Job in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, timer-jobs, custom-code

I'm trying to create a custom timer job in Sharepoint. The job will send an e-mail message to the users that subscribed.

I want to make a settings page for users, so they can change their own preferences for the digest service. For example, how often they want to receive mails (weekly, bi-weekly, monthly etc.), which Sharepoint lists they want to receive summary of, or an "on / off" switch.

How should i proceed for such a system? I'm at the beginning of the development, so your suggestions will actually shape my code.

Thanks.

### Edit:

Well, it's been almost 10 hours since i asked this question. I had an idea. I can create a settings List and add each user to this list as rows. Then have each column represent a setting. Providing a link to the DispForm.aspx file with the userId as querystring, i can redirect users from homepage to the settings page. I would like to apply the other solution anyway.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the default Alert settings, what's the differential in terms of requirements for this feature?

Comment: A custom page. Similar to the Alert settings but with my custom fields such as a list of Sharepoint Lists in my site. So the user can select which lists he/she wants to get summary of.

Answer (score 0):

I think a CustomAction would let you put a settings page where you want it. For data storage, using a list as you suggest would work, but it would probably be better to store the settings in user profile properties.

Comment: It would create another WSP beside from my Custom Timer Job WSP, right? Thanks.

Comment: That would be one option, though an additional feature in the same WSP would probably be more convenient.